# Does the FL1 train now go directly to Termini in Rome?

Tags: trains, airport-transfer, rome, train-stations

The [offical travel planner](http://muovi.roma.it/percorso/js/?a=Via%20Marsala%2C%20Roma&tipi_ris=&linee_escluse=-&piedi=1&bus=1&quando=2&da=Point%20on%20map%20%3Cpunto%3A%2841.791771%2C12.25339%29%3E%2C%20&hl=en&dt=2015-08-03%2018%3A30%3A00&cp=1&mezzo=1&ztl=&bici_sul_tpl=0&max_distanza_bici=5.0&metro=1&ferro=1) (also on google maps) it says that the FL1 train goes directly to Rome central station (Termini). But [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FL1_(Lazio_regional_railways)) and other pages says it doesn't , which is correct?

Comment: A couple of months ago when I used it, FL1 didn't and you had to change, or you could take the more expensive Leonardo Express direct to Termini

Comment: Yes, that's what I am reading everywhere too. But it does not align very well with the offical travel planner...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being the FL1 a regional train operated by Ferrovie dello Stato, I would trust their official FS site more than the ATAC journey planner (or Google for that matter). [The FS page on the Airport train services says that the FL1 takes you from Fiumicino to *most* train stations within Rome.](http://www.trenitalia.com/tcom-en/Services/Fiumicino-Airport) These are (ordered by closest distance from the airport):

- Roma Trastevere
- Roma Ostiense
- Roma Tuscolana
- Roma Tiburtina

Quoting from the linked FS page:

> #### FL1 REGIONAL TRAIN to and From Rome/Fiumicino Airport
>
> With trains departing every 15 minutes Trenitalia’s FL1 regional train takes you from Leonardo da Vinci Airport to the main train stations in Rome (Trastevere, Ostiense, Tuscolana and Tiburtina).
> The train also stops in many other important stations in Rome, and travels as far as Fara Sabina/Orte.

It would therefore seem that to date the FL1 train **does not stop at Roma Termini**. [For more information here is a PDF with the full list of stops.](http://www.trenitalia.com/cms-file/allegati/trenitalia_2014/informazioni/Schema_linea_FL1_tcom2014.pdf) Below is a map of the regional train network, courtesy of Wikimedia:

[image: Rome regional network map]